# why do all bad hostnames resolve to 198.105.254.23?

Tags: networking, dns

I'm running 14.04 on a desktop and laptop connected to a DSL router and am unable to get any of the internal hostnames to resolve correctly. When I dig desktopname:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> desktopname
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39208
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;desktopname.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
desktopname.        10  IN  A   198.105.254.23
desktopname.        10  IN  A   198.105.244.23

;; Query time: 64 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Oct 17 20:18:11 PDT 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 61

cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Your ISP is probably serving a domain-not-found page. E.g: http://askubuntu.com/q/49817/158442

Comment: so - how to i fix it?

Comment: Change your DNS provider as described in the answers to [“What is the proper way to change the DNS IP?”](https://askubuntu.com/q/2321/175814). You may be able to change the DNS server entry in your router to affect everyone in your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

This is your ISP (in this case, Centurylink) trying to be helpful and resolve all unresolvable domains to a "helper" page that shows you a list of search results

[image: Centurylink Webhelper]

According to their "Why am I here link?":

> The CenturyLink Web Helper service provides helpful search results to
>   our customers when they would otherwise encounter web address errors.
>   You are seeing search results offered by the CenturyLink Web Helper
>   service because you clicked on an invalid link or entered an invalid
>   Web address into the address bar of your browser. Misspellings and
>   typing errors frequently cause these errors. In instances where the
>   site you were looking for is clear, you may not see this page at all.
>   Instead, the service may take you directly to the site.