# Just installed 11.04, and web browsing is slow/nonexistent. Download speeds good

Tags: 11.04

I just installed 11.04 after running win7 with 11.04 for a while with no problems.  The internet seemed fine because I was just downloading stuff with software update and things like that, but when I went to use firefox, and them chromium, all I get is 1. a page that says the page I'm looking for is unavailable, and 2. when I reload, the page sometimes comes in, but in a plain text format, and then it's super-spotty.  I've been looking here for something that might help me figure it out, but so far no joy.  I'm a newbie, but I ran ifconfig, but don't know how to interpret it.  I don't know how to figure out what drivers I have or even what type of card I have.  I have a dell 1012 netbook.  Tell me what to do.  I'm having to use a different computer for the internet right now.  Thanks.

Comment: This might be due to a bad nameserver, try using an other nameserver (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are from Google and publicly available)

Comment: How do I do that?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: you might want to have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip

Answer (score 1):

OP solved issue Thanks! That solved it. Awesome!!! – Brendon Aug 14 '11 at 23:07

by using this link:

[What is the proper way to change the DNS IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip)