# How to change the DNS name server?

Tags: dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper way to change the DNS IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip)

How to change the  DNS NameServer in Ubuntu 11.04,  When I typed node.ws on browser url-bar it redirected me to sedoparking.com site; How can I change to google DNS ie, 8.8.8.8

### Here is the attachement:

[image]