# How can I change DNS servers?

Tags: 11.10, networking, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the DNS name server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59146/how-to-change-the-dns-name-server)

I have a Ubuntu 11.10 machine, and I'd like to change my DNS servers. How do I do this?