# Not using a proxy but still getting "Something wicked happened resolving.." error

Tags: 12.04

I've been searching online for the last few days and have found many people with the same error but none with answers that fix mine as I'm NOT using a proxy :(

When I run `apt-get update` I get the following error:

```
Something wicked happened resolving 'http-proxy:8080' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

I went to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and this was written in it:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://http-proxy:8080";
```

It's complaining about this proxy it seems, but there is no proxy set on my home network! I deal with proxies at work so know how to get around them, but I deleted the entry from `apt.conf` and this still didn't help.

Comment: There was 95proxy, I deleted that and it started working again!!! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked, I made an answer from my comment (comments may get lost over time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf` there is a directory `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`. All files in there can contain settings for *apt*. They are named with a 2 digit number and then their purpose (like `00trustcdrom` or `99proxy`). The numbers are there to ensure the intended order.
(I was not able to determine if in case of *conflicting* statements the *later* ones or the *earlier* ones are in effect - my **guess** is : later statements overwrite earlier ones).
So if settings in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` don't work have a look at files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Settings** / **Network**.

On the left side panel, click "**Network proxy**".

In the "**Method**" box, choose "**None**". Click on "**Apply system wide**".

Open a Terminal window and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

"...this problem is ... a short-lived problem with (or accessing) ***your*** DNS server. (The problem is not actually with the server at  "http://archive.scrapy.org/" itself, though it may have been due to a configuration problem for that server's DNS record.)" Quotation from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/142511/156684).