# Proxy settings not working in ubuntu12.04 but working fine with windows 7

Tags: proxy, authentication

Proxy authentication settings are set properly in the /etc/apt/apt.conf and even in the network settings. But the sudo apt-get update command gives an error "something wicked happend in resolving proxy. (-5 - no hostname attached ) . This happens only with the connection in my room. It works normally with the internet connection in my friends room. But again the strange thing is, I have a windows 7 alongside ubuntu 12.04 and the proxy settings are working properly in windows (even with my room's connection). Any help could be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "-5 No address associated with hostname error" while updating?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142508/how-to-fix-5-no-address-associated-with-hostname-error-while-updating)

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that the line in the /etc/apt/apt.conf is in the following format:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@yourproxy:80";
```

This is including the ; on the end, and the quotes on each end of the address.
You could shorten it to the following when no authentication is necessary.

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://yourproxy:80";
```