# Failed to resolve repositories when running apt-get

Tags: apt

I've been looking at this for days along the forums, and no one seems to have a satisfactory answer.

I'm running raring, completely default. I repeatedly see "Something wicked happened resolving..." messages for several repositories, including the default Ubuntu us archive.

When installing Steam through the Software Center, it adds the repository for Steam specific packages (repo.steampowered.com). When installing Chrome, it also installs a new repository.

When I force Ubuntu to use an outside resolver (both on the internal network, as well as the public 4.2.2.2), the error is solved when trying to pull packages from the Ubuntu repositories, but I still get the error for outside repositories.

However, I can easily resolve these domains using any of the resolvers:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'dl.google.com:http' (-11 - System error)

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'repo.steampowered.com:http' (-11 - System error)

$ nslookup repo.steampowered.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   repo.steampowered.com
Address: 208.64.203.149

$ nslookup repo.steampowered.com 4.2.2.2
Server:     4.2.2.2
Address:    4.2.2.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   repo.steampowered.com
Address: 208.64.203.149
```

Comment: +1. Interesting. Usually I only see this error if it's unable to resolve these hostnames.

Comment: did you try `wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release.gpg`? If it works it means that something wicked happens with your apt-get, and you are hitting a weird bug.

Comment: I have tried using wget to obtain the gpg files and this works just fine. It only occurs when using APT.
<pre>
Resolving repo.steampowered.com (repo.steampowered.com)... 208.64.203.149
Connecting to repo.steampowered.com (repo.steampowered.com)|208.64.203.149|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 490
Saving to: ‘Release.gpg’

100%[======================================>] 490         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-08-27 18:46:25 (38.7 MB/s) - ‘Release.gpg’ saved [490/490]
</pre>

Comment: Do not use comments to provide facts, [edit] the question and add them there.

Comment: "Something wicked happened" errors from APT only very rarely indicate a bug. I wouldn't recommend rushing to that conclusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "-5 No address associated with hostname error" while updating?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142508/how-to-fix-5-no-address-associated-with-hostname-error-while-updating)

Comment: @guntbert This is -11 errors..

Comment: -5 or -11, in any case its an error message from the DNS server.

Comment: This seems to have stopped on its own; at present (days later) I'm no longer getting errors when resolving these hostnames. It seems to be a DNS issue, but I'm still concerned as to why it failed when resolutions were working outside of APT, using multiple resolvers and on different networks. 

The error was not from the nameserver; it was localized only within apt. All resolutions worked fine outside of apt.

Comment: This is so infuriating. I've searched everywhere for an explanation of this `-11 - System Error`, but I can't find anything. I can't even find official `apt-get` documentation that lists all possible errors. The only thing I've found was [this facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/mjma3/posts/10151518144817084) (in Arabic), and the person solved it by `rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` but it doesn't make any sense =/. I'm flagging this question to be closed because it's not a reproducible error and it seemingly went away.

Comment: similar problem involving repo.steampowered.com happen just after updating steam, I restarted my system then the update ran fine.