# cannot browse although connected to internet

Tags: networking, apt, updates, internet

`zati@zati-K42JZ:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for zati:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg

  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg

  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg

  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.canonical.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg

  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg

  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release

Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise Release

Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg

  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages/DiffIndex

Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release

Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex

Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release

Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex

Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex

Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex

Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex

Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex

Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages

  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.canonical.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages

  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US

  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.canonical.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US

  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex

Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en

  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.canonical.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en

  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex

20% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com]`
yesterday i tried to install a management system into my 12.04 ubuntu. I tried to edit the repository in sources.list using sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list . I am not sure whether i type it correctly, i only type the deb http://dms.oscc.org.my/repo binary/ as told in the website. when i want to apt-get update, it execute a -5 error. why is that happening? it execute -5 error for archive and security too.

and then i tried to figure out solutions but while doing that(i follow some solutions posted by other people), then my sources.list only left with two lines. so it is corrupted right?

next, i tried to access the internet, but it says it cant found servers. when i tried to ping google.com, it says unknown host. i can ping my router successfully but other than that, it fails.

i am really a newbie in using ubuntu, and i hope you guys can help me, and that'll means a lot since i am currently doing my internship. thankyou in advance

Comment: Firstly I don't think you are not asking the right question. Secondly can post  error you are getting.. Start from the start what error are you getting when you run `sudo apt-get update` 
p.s mark your code as code. 
cheers

Comment: @serine I'm sorry, I tried to post my code but it says its too long

Comment: I can't see anything..

Comment: Welp, my mistake. I have edit my question altogether with the code. Thankyou for your effort to help me @serine. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it is some what tricky to get you the right advice given that you've probably modified files in few places. At least that's how I read your question.

**step one** 
Trace you steps back and undo everything you did.

`sources.list` has certain syntax to it and I don't think you can append just any URL to it. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197564/how-do-i-add-a-line-to-my-etc-apt-sources-list) looks like a good guide for future reference, on how to add links to you `sources.list`. Please note that step one in editing you `sources.list` is to **back the current one up**.

**step two**

I would just save all the data in your `/home/$USER` directory (that is your home directory) and reinstall ubuntu (might as well install the latest stable release [Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Ubuntu installation takes less 30 minutes). This to me the easiest way to fix all broken files in several places (not the most sophisticated solution)

`tar -zcvf backup.tar.gz /home/$USER` is the easiest way. This will make single file with all of you stuff in home directory (might take a while to make such file)

**step three**

Here is a solution to [`-5 - No address associated with hostname`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142508/how-to-fix-5-no-address-associated-with-hostname-error-while-updating)

It looks like from that answer that all you need to do to fix `-5 - No address associated with hostname` is clean up you `/etc/hosts` file

this is how my `/etc/hosts` file looks in Ubuntu 14.04

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       *your computer name*

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouter
```

Comment: thank you serine. Its just my laptop cannot handle the Ubuntu 14.04 version so that is why I use the 12.04 version. but thank you so much for your help

Comment: have you tried step three..?