# Ubuntu DNS back to normal

Tags: dns, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper way to change the DNS IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip)

Yesterday, I change my DNS into google DNS because my ISP has place so many restriction..

So I edit my resolv.conf file and it's look like this..

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
#nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

But, when I login in my ubuntu, I try to look at my favourite site, but it's show could not connected, so I begins to suspect with my DNS, so I look back, and suprisingly, it's become normal back..

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

So my question, how to make this file don't revert to using default DNS ? I want google DNS, not my ISP DNS..
I'm using new ubuntu 12.10, in 12.04, this problem doesn't occur..

Comment: But my problem occur in ubuntu 12.10, in 12.04, this problem doesn't exist to me

Comment: @Mohd - just try the fix suggested in the thread referred to by dobey, it should work.

Comment: Read the comment at the top of the file! To gain more understanding, open a terminal and type "man resolvconf" and start reading, pressing the space bar to page down through the manual page. If you really want 8.8.8.8 always to be listed as a nameserver, add it to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base. But note that this is not the most correct configuration; better is to configure either ifup or NetworkManager to use 8.8.8.8 as the nameserver address for your network interface when it configures the interface.