# How to use a specific DNS on wifi connection?

Tags: networking, dns, download-speed

I read a few articles which stated that my isp(BSNL) has weak DNS servers and using a different faster DNS like opendns or google will increase the speed.

I use a wifi connection through the router. Now i want to assign the google DNS to my connection as google is giving me the least ping time.

how do i do this?

A step by step guide if possible please!

I am geting just 30KB/s right now, I am using 12.10 if needed as info.

Comment: The best solution is to change the DNS at the router, as the router directs all Internet traffic from your WiFi devices. How to do it is depends on the make and model of the router and is off-topic here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to change the DNS IP?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-configure-dns-nameserver-ip-address/) will give you generic instructions that will always work system wide.

From inside Unity, click the wireless app indicator.
Go to the wireless tab
select your wireless connection
go to the IPV4 settings (assuming your using a pretty standard router)
change the drop down to Automatic DHCP addresse only
then in the DNS servers box put in DNS servers you want to use.

Save and exit, and you should be done.

Comment: The link you provide shows how to change it system-wide, bypassing NetworkManager and potentially breaks when accessing protected public or business networks requiring the use of the local DNS resolver. So, for mobile devices this is not recommended.

Comment: Yes I was providing both methods, the link for "Can't possibly not work" i.e. changes everything every where. And the more "user friendly" approach (which does the exact same thing, just in a more automated fashion). I have edited my answer to make it clear that the link is system wide.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would like to suggest to change the resolver in your router if possible. All hosts connected will be able to benefit the higher speed.

If you can't or just need to use this on one machine, add it here in NetworkManager:

[image]

Be sure to select "Automatic (DHCP) **addresses only**" in order to be able to enter the DNS resolver(s). The screenshot is taken in KDE, but should look very similar in GNOME/Unity environments.