# Can't load some domain

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome, 13.04, lynx

I can't load some domain on my ubuntu 13.04:

- youtube.com
- translate.google.com
- drive.google.com
- vk.com

When I ping them they are responding:

```
PING youtube.com (217.119.79.59) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from non-registered.plix.pl (217.119.79.59): icmp_req=1 ttl=59 time=21.9 ms
64 bytes from non-registered.plix.pl (217.119.79.59): icmp_req=2 ttl=59 time=20.5 ms
64 bytes from non-registered.plix.pl (217.119.79.59): icmp_req=3 ttl=59 time=21.3 ms
--- youtube.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 20.544/21.255/21.914/0.560 ms
```

But they don't load in any browser like firefox, chrome, lynx. They load in my media centre on XBMCbuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check / change your DNS.

Set your DNS server to 8.8.8.8 and apply. This solution will work everywhere and you will always get the domain that you have chosen.To do this, follow the answers from this question: [What is the proper way to change the DNS IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip)

Comment: But DNS seems to be working correctly; 217.119.79.59 seems to be a Google IP.

Comment: worked: from this is clear, that your DNS was set incorrectly. Always is better to have DNS close to your computer, mostly the local router. To apply the google DNS (8.8.8.8) everywhere sounds as potential future problem. I suppose to give 8.8.8.8 as a secondary DNS, if the primary does not work/respond.

Comment: @Dee I have not said to apply everywhere. I said only that this solution will work everywhere. And maybe others, like OpenDNS: 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220. I choose 8.8.8.8 because OP had problems with Google sites.

Comment: I think that Google's DNS is the best option when you are using different networks.