# Connecting to wrong IP

Tags: updates, sudo

```
sudo apt-get update
```

When I try this command on terminal it says:

```
0% [Connecting to 107.108.85.10 (107.108.85.10)] [Connecting to 107.108.85.10 (1
```

Which I'm not sure is which IP... It's definitely not my IP address. How to resolve this?

Comment: But the update is ending with success?

Comment: @Radu - I get a PTR record that can't resolve and doesn't respond to pings on the listed IP address.

Comment: @douggro Try to follow step 2 from the answer.

Comment: @Radu - Nothing wrong with my DNS. Ran the IP through MXtoolbox and it failed there as well, saying the PTR record lookup failed after the name server timed out. Flat unreachable IP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your internet connectivity. Try `ping www.google.com` to see if it's working correctly.
2. Try to check / change your DNS. To do this, follow the answers from this question: [What is the proper way to change the DNS IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip)

Answer (score -2):

This is what I did:

1. Go to System Settings
2. Network
3. Network proxy (Method choose None and then Apply system wide)

[image: Screenshot]