# Facebook photos don't appear on firefox and google chrome

Tags: facebook

I use Ubuntu 13.04 OS and when I install Google Chrome and Firefox and open Facebook for the first 2 days it works perfect, and suddenly some images don't appear like my friends profile pictures or shared photos while others appear, this is a print screen.

[image]

This problem occurs with facebook only.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache of your browser? Also try to press `Shift + F5` to force reload all the contents. Another problem might be DNS issues - try using a different DNS (Google or OpenDNS) - see this question on how to do that - [What is the proper way to change the DNS IP?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Account Settings > Security Settings > Secure Browsing and uncheck this option: "Browse Facebook on a secure connection (https) when possible". Then save changes and refresh Facebook.

Comment: Apparently I'm the only person in the world that doesn't have the secure browsing option in my FB account settings. Any other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your network connection settings, and change the DNS servers to point to Google's public DNS servers:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  My AdBlock Plus addon had a "Add your own filter" for Facebook.  Don't know how it got there but I removed it and everything worked after.  To remove it, click on the ABP (Addblock Plus) icon.  Click on the "Option" choice at the bottom of that block.  Click on the "Add your on filters tab".  Finally, remove the offending Facebook filter.