# DNS Server or NameServer

Tags: 12.04, networking, dns

Edit connection  Mobile Broadband : select network name :  Edit IP4 settings: Under Methods : Automatic PPP and Automatic PPP address only

Changed  DNS Server to: 198.153.192.40  and Search Domains To: 198.153.194.40 
Yet the output of `$ cat /etc/resolv.conf:`  Is

```
Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search 198.153.194.40
```

It is the same output on wireless network also.

Is this normal for nameserver?

Out put of Cat /etc/issue :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

Am having many intrusions to my PC and wonder if that is a contribute factor.

Although, DNS test like (www.dnsleaktest.com) does show what was implemented at "Edit Connections"  That is the IP address' of the public DNS added.

Ubuntu Network Tools (3.2.0) shows:

Devices:
Network Devices: Loopback interface (lo)
Protocol:   IPv6  IP address:  ::1  Netmask: 128  Scope: Host
Protocol: IPv4    IP address:    127.0.0.1    Netmask: 255.0.0.0         Scope:

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is normal. On Ubuntu Desktop since 12.04 there is a `dnsmasq` instance listening on the the loopback interface at address 127.0.0.1 (127.0.1.1 in 12.10 and later) that functions as a forwarder for DNS queries.

However, it is not normal to set `search` to an IP address. You may delete the `Search Domain` entry; it is not necessary on consumer desktop installations.

You can test the local nameserver with something like

```
dig google.com @127.0.0.1
```

Dnsmasq receives upstream nameserver addresses via NetworkManager->DBUS->dnsmasq.

Comment: This question and many others: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip) show that user can change/reset DNS in use rather than the loop-back server. Although it is understood that wireless local network is different from a broadband that also a wireless WAN configured independently from Network Manger IP4 DNS sittings.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Could you rephrase? Do you experience a malfunction? I understood the OP as of pure interest, not as a request for help on any issue.

Comment: Yes, I do get frozen browsers , invalid signatures while updating from respiratory, and some intrusions from time to time. So am trying to make sure that Internet configuration is the correct one. Thanks.