# Problem with resolv.conf

Tags: resolv.conf

I made these changes to resolv.conf today and when i restarted my laptop i cannot connect to the internet. It says server cant be found. These commands were given to me by unoDNS when trying to delete it from my system.

```
sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bak
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee  /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

Any suggestions as to what went wrong. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: You need to describe what steps you took exactly. Normally you set your DNS in Network manager, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip

Comment: What precisely are the symptoms and problems you have when trying to get online?

Comment: i cant remember the steps exactly but it involved resolv.conf and entering 8.8.8.8 into it, and then 8.8.4.4. when i restarted my router and laptop i cant access the internet. it says server cannot be reached

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: from the file `# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN` so why do you edit it? it is not the correct place

Answer (score 3):

When you did `sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bak` you removed what was probably the symbolic link to the dynamically generated file /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf.

To restore the symbolic link do the following

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

and then reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Your system use resolvconf and the file resolv.conf is generated dynamically. To properly update the nameserver you can put the dns parameters in:

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 1.1.1.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 1.1.1.2
 dns-names 8.8.8.8
```

or Menu > Settings > Network > Wired > Edit > IPv4 > DNS > Server: 8.8.8.8 and then reboot.