# Global DNS change

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

How do I change my DNS server globally without having to do it manually through network manager for every connection I have.

I want to use OpenDNS, whether its at home, university, wifi hotspot, phone tether...

I use Ubuntu 13.10 but I guess it will be the same on newer versions.

Comment: @Paul: your url changed to https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#name-resolution

Comment: This is not a duplicate, but it will show how to change dns for **one connection**: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip

Comment: @rubo77 Thanks. I deleted the comment since it had no other information.

Answer (score 5):

You can add this file so network manager will update `resolv.conf` [each time a connection is established](http://www.mydailyhacks.org/2012/03/12/networkmanager-dispatcher/):

```
echo "echo 'nameserver 85.214.20.141'>/etc/resolv.conf"> /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-FoeBud-dns
chmod +x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-FoeBud-dns
```

(I would suggest the dns 85.214.20.141 ([FoeBud](http://www.foebud.org/aboutus/gegen-internetsperren-in-einer-freien-gesellschaft-foebud-richtet-anti-zensur-dns-server-ein)))

#### Evaluation:

```
watch cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then restart networkmanager in another console with

```
service network-manager restart
```

... watch changing the `resolv.conf` file.

#### Drawback:

The local DNS caching on your machine by `dnsmasq` will not be available any more.

---

**I also tried:**

```
echo "nameserver 85.214.20.141">/etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf
echo "resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf" > /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/FoeBud-dns
```

which seemed somewhat cleaner or a shorter option would be:

```
echo "server=85.214.20.141" > /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/FoeBud-dns
```

But both options don't seem to work, because Network-Manager does start his own instance of `dnsmasq`which does not use those standard dnsmasq conf files.

A solution to this would be to detach dnsmasq from NetworkManager and install dnsmasq on its own (see https://superuser.com/a/809716/160420) but I personally don't want to change so much on my default Ubuntu system.

Comment: You could use https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ to test for your running DNS.

Answer (score 2):

You can **append** a line in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` like

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Don't fear to edit it even though there is the line 'DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND'

This file is used by *resolvconf* ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man8/resolvconf.8.html)) to generate /etc/resolv.conf, which is used by *NetworkManager*

After that you need to run, *once*

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Comment: Will this keep the dnsmasq functionality? Or will it have the  same drawback as my solution?

Comment: @rubo77 I've tried this before with my college wifi, and `nm-tool` would report the dns provided by the access point, not by resolv.conf so I would assume this preserves dnsmasq functionality. In my solution bellow, `supersede` option basically tells dhcp to replace whatever access point provides with its own dns server. `prepend` option might be better, as you still receive what dhcp provided AND add additional,custom dns that you specify

Comment: @rubo77 if you look at the resulting /etc/resolv.conf you end up with 2 lines nameserver the first being the one from head here 8.8.8.8 and the second 127.0.0.1. So first it tries to use google dns, and second locahost/dnsmasq.

Comment: This has the same Drawback: The local DNS caching on your machine by dnsmasq will not be available any more, every dns request will be made to the external DNS, so this is much slower.

Comment: Although this is not the solution, you get the bounty for your hint: "You could use https://dnsleaktest.com to test for your running DNS." ;)

Answer (score 1):

**METHOD #1: scripting**

As you may know , you can change dns for particular connecton using `nm-connection-editor` (which is what opens when you hit Edit Connections in the network icon). That's the graphical way.

The terminal based way would be to edit each connection in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` folder, by adding lines `dns=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx;` and `ignore-auto-dns=true` after `[ipv4]` and `method=auto`. Here's a sample file from `/etc/Network-Manager/system-connections/`:

```
[connection]
id=My College Connection
uuid=*******-******-****-a155-ca880ccf7ddb
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=My College Connection
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=00:0B:81:94:D3:08

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=auto
dns=208.67.220.220;
ignore-auto-dns=true
```

Now, what if we could automate adding these two lines to every connection configuration file ? With `grep` and `awk` it's possible! My script bellow does exactly that.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date: May 6, 2015
# Description: this script checks all settings for connections in 
# /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ , and if there's no custom
# dns set , this script sets it;
# NOTE: run sudo service network-manager restart after running this script

# set -x

for file in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/* ; do
        grep 'dns=208.67.220.220;' "$file"  || ( awk '{print;if ($1=="[ipv4]"){
getline; print "method=auto\ndns=208.67.220.220;\nignore-auto-dns=true"}}' "$fi
le" > .tmpfile && ( cat .tmpfile > "$file") )
done
```

And here is screenshot of the script at work:

[image]

**NOTE:** for 15.04 this script does not seem to work, but turns out `nmcli` has added a feature that allows modifying connection settings. The alternative to the script above is the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
for file in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*; do
    file=$(echo $file | cut -d'/' -f5-)
    nmcli connection modify id "$file" +ipv4.dns "" +ipv4.dns 208.67.220.220 +ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
done
```

**METHOD #2**
My personal favorite is to use `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, to uncomment line `supersede domain-name-servers` line and add your dns servers there , separated by comma. Screenshot bellow is from the web, belongs to debian, however it is equally used in ubuntu. I use this very same trick in both mint 17 and ubuntu 14.04 . Among other things I'd suggest commenting out line `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` but it's not required.

`supersede` option basically replaces whatever dns you receive from your access point (aka router). For me, `nm-tool` reports same dsn that I placed on that line for any wifi connection. `prepend` on the other hand only adds whatever you specify as secondary dns in addition to what router provides.So that may be slightly better option.

[image]

Comment: Why should I "commenting out line dns=dnsmasq"??? I want my fast local dns cache (which is dnsmask, isn't it?) and addistionally if my computer still didnt cache an IP I want to ask the FoeBud DNS

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately it has the same drawback as my solution: it doesn't use the local dnsmasq any  more

Comment: @rubo77 I've added another solution. Please review

Comment: would this keep dnsmasq intact? so the first `dig` to a new domain takes as long as the external DNS needs and from then on the next `dig` to that same domain will only tace somwhat 5 milliseconds?

Comment: @rubo77 well, with the dns that I've added, which is 208.67.220.220 (open dns), it takes me around 220 miliseconds of query time, as reported by dig. On the first try it took about 2-3 seconds to respond but right now, it reports around 220 - 300 mseconds

Comment: @rubo77 hold on, my dnsmasq was commented out

Comment: @rubo77 yup, I uncommented `dns=dnsmasq` in my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and now query time takes 32ms. `nm-tool` still reports DNS I specified

Comment: Added information related to newer release, 15.04

Answer (score -5):

You can do that by simply configuring dns in your modem/router itself henceforth all your connections will use that dns by default. Type 192.168.0.1 in your browser page to access your router/modem page.
208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220 are the two opendns servers.

Comment: How would that work at "uni, wifi hotspot, phone tether" ??

Comment: well if you are using broadband(wired connection) and sharing the same broadband over wifi,tether etc. the dns configured at your modem would be the default, as all your internet no matter how you are accessing it(wifi,tether,ethernet port) is ultimately coming/going through the modem.