# Not able to use internet despite being connected - 14.04

Tags: wireless, internet

My computer has ubuntu 14.04 and appears to be connecting to the internet. When I use firefox and try to connect to a site I get the message "Server not found."

The strange thing is that I'm able to connect and use the internet on my laptop that has Fedora 21 on it. Same with my phone.

I've tried reseting the router which doesn't work. The problem also persits for all users on my computer.

Anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: Your DNS configuration is broken?

Comment: Output for `cat /etc/resolv.conf` & `route -n` along with `ping google.com` please?

Comment: Do you know how to fix it, dobey? I'm a fairly new linux user.

Comment: @AzkerM I update the post with outputs of the commands you asked me for

Comment: Again `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @AzkerM sorry for the typo there, I actually just solved the issue though. I edited resolv.conf to match the file on my fedora laptop. I added 'nameserver 192.168.1.1'

Comment: This is due to no DNS for sure.. But adding in resolv.conf is temperory!! When you restart the settings will go off. Try adding manually from the network manager

Comment: Ok, How do I add manually from the network manager? Thank you in advance

Comment: @elliottweintraub please could you copy paste (by right clicking) the content from terminal, rather than a photo?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/2325/179042

Answer (score 0):

If `/etc/resolv.conf` does not exist. You must create one and enter the nameserver line

For Example

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Where 8.8.8.8 is the Google DNS Server. You need to put in your DNS Server IP Address.

Note:- `/etc/resolv.conf` Should automatically get generated but if it is absent you need to create it. After that it should stay there.

Comment: Thanks for setting the format Correct. Appreciate it , Tim !!

Comment: typically all Linux system will have that file and chances are less of missing it unless its removed by User. Also, its clearly a typo error by OP. Further, adding DNS on `/etc/resolv.conf` is temporary as it will be vanished upon a system restart.

Comment: Yes correct. It will wipe out the contents but the file itself remains available for the network scripts to write to. If the file is missing then you have no internet. Just creating a blank file and restarting the Network Daemon or the Machine should be sufficient to regenerate the contents of the file.!