# how to use a router as DNS server?

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, dns, router

While [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/2325/45156) solution seems to work fine, can I instead just use the [NetGear WNR1000v2 - N150 Wireless Router](http://www.netgear.com/support/product/WNR1000v2) itself as a DNS server?  (I had an odd circumstance where the [VOIP phone](https://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=439346) worked fine, but nothing else.  Everything is still slow to resolve pages.)

Comment: Well it depends, are you hoping for basic DNS resolution or are you wanting to create forward/reverse zones etc ? What make and model is your router? I think you may need to edit your question with the make/model of your router and what you are trying to achieve with the DNS routing

Comment: The make and model are in the link to the router.  Just the most basic kind of DNS server.  (Still have a very slow connection at the moment for some reason.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DNS server is used to resolve host names to IP address, to use that router as DNS server seems unlikely as the [manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNR1000V2/WNR1000v2h2_SM_30JULY2010.pdf) its self doesn't reference any sort of DNS server settings.

If would like to distribute a custom DNS IP address via DHCP you could follow [this](http://setuprouter.com/router/netgear/wnr1000v2/dns.htm) guide (Haven't used it, so proced with caution).

Setting up an internal DNS server wont help you (If i understand the question right). Have you done a [speed test](http://speedtest.net) on your ubuntu to see what kind of internet speed you are getting?

Comment: ping:18ms down:5.3 Mb/s up:0.5 Mb/s but it's more that it takes an inordinate amount of time load simple pages.  Slow loading, ok, but, before I added Google as a DNS server there was no way to resolve an address -- nothing was loading.  It's fixed now, just curious.  I'll check out the links, thanks.  My router had the settings in that link, which is why the VOIP hard phone worked when nothing else did.

Comment: Being honest with you that's pretty bad speed, if you weren't able to resolve any host names (Did you try any commands in the terminal?) then that could potentially be a blunder on your router setup, although the router itself should obtain its DNS settings from your ISP (If not set to a custom value).

Comment: the router and pc are using Google as per that link.  It's painfully slow at the moment, but the question was about using the router as a DNS server.   Based on your answer it's not possible with this router, I'll have to look into it a bit more.

Comment: I would probably put it down to the speed your ISP is providing you with. How are you connected to the router via WI-FI or Ethernet? If using wifi try connecting VIA Ehternet cable and try the test again. In that case if my answer answers your question please accept!

Comment: Yes, it's my ISP.  The router is using ethernet.  The original problem was that the PC, hard-wired to the router, couldn't connect either.  That was solved by fixing the DNS.  it's still slow, but that's not the question I asked.  I will accept your answer, no worries, just want to look into it a bit more to be positive that I can't use this router as a DNS server.

Comment: In the provided router manual I couldn't see anything about running a DNS server, but I really don't believe you need to run an internal DNS server!