# DNS set to systemd's 127.0.0.53 - how to change permanently?

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

I've recently upgraded to 17.10.  When I try to browse to a website, or ping a domain it fails saying the site cannot be resolved.

`network-admin` shows the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` to be `nameserver: 127.0.0.53`

If I change that to 8.8.8.8 or 208.67.222.222 then everything works.  Until I reboot.

Upon reboot or resume, the nameserver is reset to 127.0.0.53.

How do I *permanently* set the nameserver to something that works?

---

For systemd fans, if I run `systemd-resolve --status` I get

```
Link 3 (wlo1)
      Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

If I follow the advice at this question - [DNS keeps resetting after reboot. Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979002/dns-keeps-resetting-after-reboot-ubuntu-17-10) - DNS still fails to resolve.

Comment: `systemctl stop systemd-resolved` and
`systemctl mask systemd-resolved`
should do the trick :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can install the resolvconf package, which will modify the way `/etc/resolv.conf` is built up at system boot.

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

You can then create or modify a file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`.  If you put in this file a line `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, this line will be added at the end of `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` at boot.  `/etc/resolv.conf` will now be a symbolic link to this file.

**Post Scriptum:**

Almost two years after posting my answer I came across https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ppp/+bug/1778946 which explains exactly why merely installing `resolvconf` solved a dns problem I had at the time.  I feel I have to share this here.

> Although my answer addresses the question in a proper way, indeed a
> warning should be added that, if you want/need to do this, probably
> something else is wrong.   This was already stated by @intelfx at the
> time,  127.0.0.53 should work by itself.

According to that bug report, after a PPTP VPN goes down, `resolv.conf` is restored with the wrong access rights.  `ping ubuntu.com` does not work, `sudo ping ubuntu.com` does. Installing `resolvconf` solved it, because it takes over `resolv.conf`, restoring it with correct rights.  Changing `systemd-resolve` settings is no solution in this case, since the bug is in `ppp`.  But an alternative, maybe simpler solution is `sudo chmod a+r /etc/resolv.conf` after VPN down.  And this can be automated by putting an executable script in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ "$1"="ppp0" && "$2"="vpn-down" ]]; then  
    /bin/chmod a+r /etc/resolv.conf
fi
```

In all cases, the contents of `resolv.conf` do not change.
And, yes, I know PPTP must be avoided because of security issues, but at the time I thought of it as a good exercise for an Ubuntu newbie.  I imagined it would work out of the box.  Little did I know that it would give me a headache, as diagnosed so well by @intelfx.

Comment: This works - thank you! Do you know if there's any way to get 127.0.0.53 to work by itself?

Comment: I am fairly new to this matter.  Just have been trying to get rid of dns problems when switching vpn on/off over the last weeks.  You could try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`.  I tried this lately, cleared the tail file, and at first this seems to work.

Comment: @TerenceEden if you are looking to make 127.0.0.53 to work by itself (as it should), take a look at my answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1083843/281191

Comment: I'll have to show my ignorance here, but what happened to the practice of using the DNS server handed out by the DHCP server on your network?? My firewall (OPNsense) is set up to do that, and I'd really like to have my Ubuntu boxen use the DNS that **I choose**. Maybe that's what is happening here, but wtf is 127.0.0.53... loopback w/ DNS port # as part of IP addr?! :)

Comment: @Seamus nothing happened to that practice. It is widely considered useful to use DNS stub resolvers and cache DNS responses wherever possible. Your provider will have their own DNS servers that point to root DNS servers and cache their responses, then your router (if you use something sane like OpenWrt) will run dnsmasq that points to the ISP's DNS servers and cache _their_ responses, and finally your Linux system will also run a caching DNS resolver that points to the router and caches its responses. 127.0.0.53 is the address of that caching DNS resolver.

Comment: In my case, with PIA VPN on Ubuntu 18.04, /etc/resolv.conf always ended up containing only "nameserver 127.0.0.1" after each reboot or PIA connection, so I had to manually replace it with "nameserver 127.0.0.53" for internet to work on my computer. Just adding "nameserver 127.0.0.53" in /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail and now it automatically appends it in /etc/resolv.conf after reboot or PI connect/disconnect, so internet works properly and automatically. Probably not the cleanest setup but finally working for me.

Answer (score 45):

The *correct* solution would be to fix systemd-resolved instead of trying to cure migraine with a guillotine.

It is a nice tool, really, if used properly.

Judging by your `systemd-resolve --status` output...

> ```
> Link 3 (wlo1)
>       Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
>        LLMNR setting: yes
> MulticastDNS setting: no
>       DNSSEC setting: no
>     DNSSEC supported: no
> ```

...your network manager tool does not communicate per-interface DNS configuration to systemd-resolved.

Recent versions of NetworkManager will detect if `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to a resolved-generated file (`/run/systemd/resolve/*.conf` or `/usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf`) and if that's the case, communicate with resolved directly.

Alternatively, recent versions of systemd-resolved try to be compatible with the historical resolvconf interface by installing a `resolvconf` binary that does the right thing.

While either of these two solutions would be preferred, if you are looking for a quick and dirty fix, you can just configure systemd-resolved to use your DNS servers globally:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
<...>
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
<...>
```

Then restart `systemd-resolved.service` or reboot.

Comment: At least for me this answer doesnt work, using ubuntu 18.04, after change the "DNS" entry it keep usint the 127.0.0.53

Comment: @AndréM.Faria learn how resolved works. `127.0.0.53` is the address of the local caching stub resolver. It forwards DNS requests to whatever upstream DNS servers you specify.

Comment: Sometimes you know something and just ignore it, yes you right.

Comment: Also good to note here, is that by default `systemd-resolved` caches DNS responses. While this may be useful sometimes, it can cause problems in some situations. Uncomment the `cache=yes` line in the config file in the answer and set it to `no`.

Comment: what actually causes `/etc/resolve.conf` (or really,  `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`, which the former points to) to be updated? would be nice to know for testing, without a presumed reboot being required.  all i can say is that restarting `systemd-resolved.service` did not seem to do the trick

Comment: @bbarker If systemd-resolved is active and configured to work as a local caching stub resolver (which is the premise of this question and this answer) `/etc/resolv.conf` will point to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, not `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Linking to stub-resolv.conf causes dns queries to hang indefinitely. Linking to resolv.conf had no issues.

Comment: @nyanpasu64 Ensure that `DNSStubListener=` is set to `yes` in your `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, then try to query `127.0.0.53` directly (i. e. `nslookup google.com 127.0.0.53`).

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I can't believe the other suggested solution is to edit the template of resolvconf...

Comment: I got to a botched status on my Debian box, and somehow, `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved` was enough to fix it. It doesn't feel good that the service seems to go down sometimes. `systemctl` still said that `systemd-resolved` was `active (running)`, and `"Processing requests..."`.

Comment: Is the change of the `dns` entry in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` permanent?

Comment: @Timo it is permanent, in the sense that the operating system will not try to overwrite it.

Comment: in Ubuntu 22.04 the command `systemd-resolve --status` is no more... is there a substitute?

Comment: @am70 yes, it has been renamed to `resolvectl` (because the command syntax was changed and stabilized).

Answer (score 15):

**working within the `systemd` paradigm add a DNS to a link / device**

- [systemd.network manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html)

using *ubuntu 17.10+* add a `*.network` file:

`sudo nano /lib/systemd/network/100-somecustom.network`:

100-somecustom.network ( 100 can be any number for priority, and it requires the `.network` file extension ):

```
[Match]
Name=wlo1 # the device name here

[Network] # add multiple DNS 
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=208.67.222.222
```

Then restart:

```
sudo service systemd-networkd restart
```

Also look into:

```
netplan apply
```

Then check:

```
systemd-resolve --status wlo1
```

From info page `info systemd.network` :

> In addition to `/etc/systemd/network`, **drop-in ".d"** directories **can be**
>   **placed in /lib/systemd/network or /run/systemd/network** directories.
>   Drop-in files in /etc take precedence over those in
>          /run which in turn take precedence over those in /lib. Drop-in files under any of these directories take precedence over the main
>   netdev file wherever located. (Of course, since /run is
>          temporary and /usr/lib is for vendors, it is unlikely drop-ins should be used in either of those places.)

**Another approach disable the `DNSStubListener` for usage with `dnsmasq`:**

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf`:

```
#
DNSStubListener=false
```

related:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1153203/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-resolved-dns-lookups-randomly-fail
- [DNS at systemd's 127.0.0.53 is ignoring some lookups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040595/dns-at-systemds-127-0-0-53-is-ignoring-some-lookups)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304050/how-to-avoid-conflicts-between-dnsmasq-and-systemd-resolved
- https://moss.sh/name-resolution-issue-systemd-resolved/

Comment: Strange is that you stated that the DNSStubListener=false, but the actual commented configuration is DNSStubListener=yes, usually the inverse of the "yes" value is "no" and not "false" who in case of "false" was usually be "true".

Comment: Your answer to create a file with extension .network didnt worked.

Answer (score 10):

I use Lubuntu & Kubuntu 18.04. I was able to overcome the DNS problem in 2 steps:

**First step:** Install `unbound` and set it to replace `systemd-resolved` as [Grégoire C](https://askubuntu.com/users/752791/gr%C3%A9goire-c) shows [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965527/dns-problems-after-upgrading-from-16-04-to-17-10-how-to-reset-the-dns-settings).

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl enable unbound-resolvconf
sudo systemctl enable unbound
```

reboot

Open as root the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

(`sudo leafpad /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` in Lubuntu 18.04 or in Kubuntu 18.04 `SUDO_EDITOR=kate sudoedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`)

and below `[main]` put this line:

```
dns=unbound
```

reboot again

**Second step:** If after the reboot the problem is still not solved, as it was in my case, start the file manager as root, go to `/etc`, delete `resolv.conf` and create a new `resolv.conf`. Leave it empty and reboot the OS. In my case after this reboot the problem disappeared.

In Kubuntu 18.04 you can't start Dolphin as root, so you can first go to `/etc` and open the terminal from there, then type `sudo su` and press *Enter* to use it as root and then delete `resolv.conf` with the command `rm resolv.conf`. Then you can create a new empty file on your desktop, name it `resolv.conf` and open a terminal from there. Use the `sudo su` command to enter the root mode for the terminal and then copy the new `resolv.conf` from your desktop to `/etc` with the command `cp resolv.conf /etc`.

**I have to add** that I did not try to do ***the second step*** before installing `unbound`, so the next time I will do so, just to see if it will be enough or not.

Comment: Why not just edit it as root and delete the contents?

Comment: @Ballie I have tried this at first, but it did not help. Also the original `resolv.conf` from `/etc` was shown as some kind of a shortcut, which is not normal, I think. This is why I decided to delete it and recreate it by creating a new empty file and naming it `resolv.conf`. And it worked. By this reason I wrote above that the next time I have to reinstall the OS, I will try to do this first, without doing the "first step" - to see if it would be enough. But the original `resolv.conf` in `/etc` needs to be removed and recreated anyway - about this I am sure.

Comment: I have just disabled systemd-resolved.service and removed the link of resolv.conf and created one manually, and it worked!

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
I don't know how my OS came into this problem in a sudden while my DNS had been working well for months.
Here is my solution:

## Install resolvconf

`$ sudo apt install resolvconf`

Find the source of `/etc/resolv.conf`.

`$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`
shows that `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symbolic link of `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

And I found that:
This file `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` is composed of:

```
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
/run/resolvconf/interface/systemd-resolved
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
```

`$ cat /run/resolvconf/interface/systemd-resolved` shows `nameserver 127.0.0.53`, which would be reset after reboot.

## Add DNS

It seems that `nameserver <my DNS>` needs to be in front of `nameserver 127.0.0.53` so that it could work.

So I add `nameserver <my DNS>` at the end of `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`.

## Update resolvconf

`$ sudo resolvconf -u`

Answer (score 5):

This is how I change my dns record on the interface configuration.

```
$ vi /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

Change name server addresses, previously it was .4 then I changed it to .3:

```
...
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 192.168.1.3
...
```

Save the configuration and then apply the configuration:

```
$ sudo netplan apply
```

After that restart the resolvectl service.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

For notes:
I did reboot the server, and changes that I made were still intact. I use the `resolvectl dns` command to verify the dns record.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. I'm surprised it's not the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Had some issues with NordVPN so decided to add to this.

Findings:
NordVPN sets `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` DNS settings when connecting.
NordVPN removes all DNS settings from `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` when disconnecting.
This causes DNS server to no longer work (since there isn't one set).

The system needs a reboot to set it back to anything at all. A standard restart of the service (`sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service`) does not work.

The solution to work around this:

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

Head over to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/

```
cd /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/
sudo nano tail
```

Add nameservers

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

Check following places for nameservers that could have been set:

```
/run/resolvconf/interface/original.resolvconf
/run/resolvconf/interface/systemd-resolved
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
/etc/systemd/resolved.conf
/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Test which DNS servers are being used with:

```
nslookup google.com

Server:         1.1.1.1
Address:        1.1.1.1#53
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but I ran into this problem. I do have to admit that I have been manually configuring my network settings via cli before and not via the inbuilt networkmanager. I run ubuntu 18.04.

So after I disabled and then re-enabled systemd.resolved.service, this erratic behaviour of randomly losing my DNS configuration was solved for me.

```
systemctl disable systemd.resolved.service
reboot
```

after reboot:

```
systemctl enable systemd.resolved.service
reboot
```

I am a relatively fresh Linux user so there must be someone that can explain the hows and why's of why this would have worked for me, but it seemed worth to mention if it can help others.

Comment: Sry to disappoint, but there must be something you did in-between that actually fixed the problem. The operations you are suggesting here can only leave the system as it was.

Comment: To my surprise, this solution which I originally saw [here](https://www.hiroom2.com/2017/08/24/ubuntu-1610-nameserver-127-0-0-53-en/), actually removed 127.0.0.53 from my /etc/resolv.conf. But it was just temporary. After a reboot the issue reappeared.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to manage the file /etc/resolv.conf manually
"man NetworkManager.conf" provides the answer.

In /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, section [main] add:
dns=none

also make sure /etc/resolv.conf is a file, not a symlink. Your changes will survive system reboot.

Most answers are unfortunately wrong or unnecessary workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missed something pretty serious.

install nmap and then run nmap 127.0.0.1, then 127.0.0.53
They have different a list of services, something is definitely listening and hiding in another ip trying to look like localhost. Then the computer is pointing to this address rather than the actual dns server... and resolving... but I did not install any dns server...

I'm looking into what that is...
localhost subnet is only supposed to have 127.0.0.1 if I remember correctly.

It sounds like a possible hack to get around firewalls.
My firewall was on and rejecting incoming and outgoing, but my outgoing should have been to one ip. My actual dns to work...

Comment: Modern Ubuntus (and some other Linux distributions) have this configured by default. The local DNS (running on IP 127.0.0.53) is for caching purposes and it's part of the "network stack".

Answer (score -1):

When using dhcp name resolution works as expected in Ubuntu.
The problems begin when you want to go static. `cat /etc/resolv.conf` will show that yor dns is 127.0.0.53 and not the ones you have in `/etc/netplan/.yaml` file. To fix this you need to remove the `/etc/resolve.conf` link and create a new one pointing to `/run/resolve/resolve.conf`

Comment: Please, edit your answer and fix some formatting...

Answer (score -2):

This required some playing around with. After I updated the setting, I rebooted. Use:

```
ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

/etc/systemd/resolved.conf
DNS=8.8.8.8
Cache=no

System resolved failed
systemctl stop systemd-resolved
systemctl disable systemd-resolved
```

---

When Comment out the "request" for

```
# domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
```

Add this line to your `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
 supersede domain-name "cwillenterprise.com";
```

---

#### Edit config file and add entry. Additional will not replace.

Add entries to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search "cwillenterprise.com"
```

#### Run to implement changes

```
resolvconf -u
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your answer to use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for the code that should be entered in files or terminal. Do not prepend `#` to “comments” to the code – it means _header_ in Markdown. Please always check the preview of your post before sending it.