# Issue with DNS resolution in resolve.conf with static IP

Tags: networking, dns, display-resolution

Apologies if this has been answered before, I searched and couldn't find a solution.

I have setup my ubuntu 16.04 desktop with a static IP. However on startup it is not able to resolve hostnames. Surprising if I manually restart the network service with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

It fixes my DNS issue. But I have to do this every time on startup.

I think the issue is with how my resolve.conf file is being auto-written on boot.

For example on boot up it has:

```
ow@ubuntu002:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

And after `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`:

```
ow@ubuntu002:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Appreciate any help with this. I can't help but try to get to the root cause of this.

EDIT:

@Simon Sudler: yes I modified `/etc/network/interfaces` as well as `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. It was based on online tutorials.

Here is the content of my interfaces file:

```
ow@ubuntu002:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
address 192.168.0.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
ow@ubuntu002:~$
```

@oscar1919: I tried your solution and it fixed the issue!

Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Where did you configure the static address, in `/etc/network/interfaces`? Can you add the entry to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a package `resolvconf`, which will modify the way `/etc/resolv.conf` is built up at system boot.
`sudo apt install resolvconf`
You can then create or modify a file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`. If you put in this file a line `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, this line will be added at the end of `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` at boot. `/etc/resolv.conf` will now be a symbolic link to this file.
(see also here ([DNS set to systemd's 127.0.0.53 - how to change permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012641/dns-set-to-systemds-127-0-0-53-how-to-change-permanently/1012648#1012648))