# change nameserver Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop

Tags: 18.04, dns

I tried two options to change the dns of my Ubuntu OS:

(1) `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`. I entered `nameserver  208.67.222.222`
`nameserver 208.67.220.220` and `nameserver 8.8.8.8`. When I enter `sudo service network-manager restart`, the default configuration is set again...

(2) I used `sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and added `prepend domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220, 8.8.8.8;`. That, too, didn't help me cofigure my new DNS Server.

What else can I do?

My last question: The default is `127.0.0.53`. Does this mean, that my Router is the DNS Server at the moment?

Comment: (1) and (2) and `127.0.0.53` (which is another `localhost` address, as is all of `127.0.0.*`) imply you're using `resolvconf`. Read `man resolvconf`

Comment: Maybe you can look up at this question:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012641/dns-set-to-systemds-127-0-0-53-how-to-change-permanently

Answer (score 0):

I found, that the [NetworkManager (NM)](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/NetworkManager/) automatically inserts the nameserver into `/etc/resolv.conf`. If you configure `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` so that it includes `dns=none`, NM stops to automatically insert the nameserver. After that, you can manually choose a dns service.