# Virtualbox Ubuntu 19.10 - can ping 8.8.8.8 but can't resolve google

Tags: networking

setup the latest virtualbox on Windows, with a VM of Ubuntu 19.10 (fresh install no changes done).

In the guest VM, I'm able to ping 8.8.8.8 successfully, However, I can't browse google and when I ping google.com, I get:

> $ ping google.com
>
> ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name
> resolution

Here's my /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

Tried adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 but no difference.

Note:

This issue is on NAT and NatNetwork.
In bridged mode everything is fine.

Comment: What kind of network have you set up? Are you in bridged mode or NAT?

Comment: Woops.
NAT.

Bridges works regullary

Comment: I'm sorry but to clarify, do you mean that you are in NAT mode but you can switch it to bridged and it works? Regularly?

Comment: The 127.0.0.X is usually used for an internal address space. 127.0.0.53 seems to be specifically for the internal cached DNS server that Ubuntu nativelly ships with. But depending on your Windows firewal and how your network passthrough is configured, this could cause some hickups. Check out [this answser here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012641/dns-set-to-systemds-127-0-0-53-how-to-change-permanently) for more details on switching off of 127.0.0.53.