# Ubuntu 18.04 DNS resolution fails after a while

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, dns

When I ping google.com on my Ubuntu 18.04, it gives me

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I would then proceed to run

```
sudo service systemd-resolved start
```

My /etc/resolv.conf has a symbolic link as shown

```
/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

The content is as follow

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

My question is after running sudo service systemd-resolved start, it would work for a while (Maybe couple of hours), then when i ping google.com again, it would give the name resolution error. How can I permanently enable my system to resolve name resolution? I believe it is something to do with the systemd-resolved? Have been experiencing this over a couple of days. Thanks

-- Update --

A hackish way would be to set up sudo crontab to restart the service every few hours.

Comment: As you say, starting the systemd-resolved can recover your situation, can you update the output of `systemctl status systemd-resolved`

Comment: When i restart it, it becomes active. but after a couple of hours it becomes inactive. How can i make this permanent? thanks

Comment: resolved, not networkd...you paste networkd state. You can update your question with those output, it is easier to see.

Comment: systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Tue 2020-02-18 01:16:03 +08; 8h ago Process: 2951 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2951 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Status: "Shutting down..."

Comment: I have editied the output of systemctl status systemd-resolved

Comment: Looks like resolved service is shut down by unknown reason. Can you update `journalctl -u systemd-resolved` output to your question, not comments?

Answer (score 2):

There is a known bug with resolved stub service, see https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10298

The workaround I found was to change the symlink for `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to
`/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

It seems to be a problem that affects static routes.  I didn't have the problem when using DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the DNS server to some different server, Like google DNS `8.8.8.8` `8.8.4.4` and see the problems still happened?

To change the DNS server permanently [DNS set to systemd's 127.0.0.53 - how to change permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012641/dns-set-to-systemds-127-0-0-53-how-to-change-permanently)

Comment: I have tried to edit /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf and changed it to 8.8.8.8 but i still encounter the issue. I am getting my ip via dhcp

Comment: Are there others device like your phone ...etc occur the same problems or just ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having same issue caused by NetworkMonitor that override my DNS settings  and crashed resolved.

So what to do here is:

```
grep resolved /var/log/syslog
```

Also you can try to see any error reports

```
grep error /var/log/syslog
```

The last command may return a bunch of lines so sort it out. If you'll find something pleas post it here.

As a variant, you can set NetworkMonitor to just ignore DNS altogether from DHCP and use a manually defined entirely.

[Credit goes to **lauc.exon.nod**](https://serverfault.com/a/810639)

Here is the command to modify an existing connection.

```
nmcli con mod <connectionName> ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
```

`connectionName` can be found by command: `nmcli con`. In the question case, it might be "System eth0"

If you want to ignore automatically configured nameservers and search domains, ie the settings passed from DHCP.

```
nmcli con mod <connectionName> ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
```

Finally, to enable the changes, bring the connection down then up:

```
nmcli con down <connectionName>
nmcli con up <connectionName>
```

Verify with `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. You should not edit `/etc/resolv.conf` manually as it is generated by NetworkManager service, it is likely to get overridden at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out launchpad bugs 1727237,1805027,1804487.  After an NXDOMAIN error (check your dmesg output), the DNS resolution falls back to a more limited UDP based protocol, and may randomly fail on well-known names.  The workaround which worked for me was to add the libnss-resolve package, which altered the /etc/nsswitch.conf hosts line to better handle certain queries.