# can ping but not browse

Tags: networking, internet, dns

I have a weird connection problem. It occured a week ago. I am on Ubuntu 20.04. I can connect to router over wireless, but I can not browse web pages. Strange thing is that Windows, IOS, mobiles connect and browse. In order for me to browse the net, my brother has to upload some files to google drive within his Iphone, then connection problem disappears. It's the only solution for the time being. I didn't call ISP because I am the only one who has that issue.
I can `ping` the domain addresses but `traceroot` fails to retrieve the route.

It appears to be a DNS issue, I tried different DNS servers both within the router and my laptop with no luck.
What I don't understand is that why only my Linux machine is affected.
I know there are many questions with the same title. I read most of them.

EDIT:

```
ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Aug 31 23:15 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I also tried to connect from `live iso` nothing changed.

EDIT2:

From within router I ran a test. I get `Ping default gateway fail` error. When my brother starts uploading again it passes all tests.

Router's `TP LINK TD-W9970`.
[image]

EDIT3:

Uploading a file to `google drive` from within my computer also keeps the connection online till the upload ends. Then I get locked out again.

Comment: "appears to be a DNS issue" based on what? can you browse (or wget) using the remote host's IP address? can you ping both by name and IP? I wonder if it is more likely a DHCP issue or an address conflict between DHCP-assigned and statically assigned LAN IPs on your network?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and also: `ls -al /etc/resilv.conf`

Comment: @steeldriver never mind my assumptions, I need your help. Using ip address in the browser didn't work.

Comment: @steeldriver I can ping both by name and ip. _I wonder if it is more likely a DHCP issue or an address conflict between DHCP-assigned and statically assigned LAN IPs on your network_ How can I debug it?

Comment: Well at the most basic level, you could go around and note down the IP addresses of all the devices... if you can access your router's web interface it may provide a list of connected devices with all their assigned IP addresses... you could also try an `nmap` scan. Of course it might **not** be an address conflict, that's just the first thing that came to mind when you mention that your brother's iphone affects your laptop's connectivity.

Comment: Probable solution and duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150239/run-resolvconf-resolv-conf-ubuntu-18-04/1150294#1150294

Comment: @chili555 I just tried your suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: "In order for me to browse the net, my brother has to upload some files to google drive within his Iphone, then connection problem disappears." What is the fix? What files? Please elaborate.

Comment: His iphone connected to the same router as my laptop. If he starts to upload any file to `google drive` then I can access to internet. Uploading any file to his `google drive` account from his`Windows laptop` or `ipad` also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix after a week of struggling.

I noticed via

```
    netstat -pnt
```

that I have many `SYN_SENT` signals but no `SYN/ACK`

entering correct key words into search engines and checking out right `Q/A`s directed me to  [@mcdizzle's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/235965/why-would-a-server-not-send-a-syn-ack-packet-in-response-to-a-syn-packet)

Appending the line `net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0` into `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
    sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0
    sysctl -p
```

made me on line.
Thank you **mcdizzle**

Answer (score 4):

In your case, /etc/resolv.conf is not pointing to systemd as expected. Therefore, please remove and recreated the link:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Reboot and let us see:

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I read the answer given by Gerald  [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209859/ubuntu-18-04-dns-resolution-fails-after-a-while] and applied it yesterday and it didn't work.

Comment: The expected link to use systemd-resolv is to use the /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

Comment: Your edit doesn't reflect the change. May we see: `sudo service systemd-resolved status`

Comment: this solved my problem where I could ping and the terminal could install packages using repository domains with no issues, but I couldn't browse. it even didn't need a reboot. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my DNS issues by adding 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to the list of DNS servers.  My /etc/resolv.conf reads like:

```
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
options edns0 trust-ad
search DOMAINS
```

I don't know if this is a canonical solution, but it works for me.