# A particular domain is not getting opened in any of my browsers at my Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: 22.04, dns, browser, domain-server

In every other device the domain can be accessed , even from console when I tried to ping its working perfectly without any packet loss. But the browsers both firefox and chrome are unable to open that domain. Its ending up with "Connection has timed out" message everytime. This is what suddenly started yesterday. Before that I didn't have any problem accessing this site.
I am not sure what can be exact issue , I tried `traceroute` to check the path of the packets and time it takes. Its working perfectly in terminal ..

```
traceroute -4 <domain name>
```

This is giving the following output

```
    traceroute to <domain Name> (<IP address>), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  reliance.reliance (192.168.29.1)  1.710 ms  1.808 ms  2.082 ms
 2  10.6.96.1 (10.6.96.1)  3.934 ms  7.428 ms  7.882 ms
 3  172.16.19.9 (172.16.19.9)  10.303 ms  10.692 ms  11.077 ms
 4  192.168.13.234 (192.168.13.234)  9.790 ms 192.168.13.232 (192.168.13.232)  9.264 ms 192.168.13.234 (192.168.13.234)  8.669 ms
 5  172.26.102.84 (172.26.102.84)  8.200 ms  11.438 ms  11.820 ms
 6  172.26.102.194 (172.26.102.194)  12.206 ms  3.075 ms  4.774 ms
 7  192.168.20.232 (192.168.20.232)  5.612 ms 192.168.20.230 (192.168.20.230)  4.901 ms 192.168.20.236 (192.168.20.236)  7.521 ms
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * 103.198.140.170 (103.198.140.170)  38.965 ms
13  103.198.140.15 (103.198.140.15)  79.230 ms 103.198.140.64 (103.198.140.64)  38.170 ms 49.45.4.86 (49.45.4.86)  73.772 ms
14  103.198.140.17 (103.198.140.17)  73.879 ms 103.198.140.15 (103.198.140.15)  72.337 ms  73.555 ms
15  * 49.45.4.82 (49.45.4.82)  76.302 ms *
16  * hnk-b4-link.ip.twelve99.net (62.115.142.87)  266.486 ms *
17  ix-ae-52-0.tcore1.hk2-hongkong.as6453.net (116.0.67.52)  107.745 ms hnk-b4-link.ip.twelve99.net (62.115.142.87)  271.685 ms *
18  hnk-b4-link.ip.twelve99.net (62.115.142.87)  267.245 ms * if-ae-37-2.tcore2.hk2-hongkong.as6453.net (116.0.93.144)  295.611 ms
19  ix-ae-52-0.tcore1.hk2-hongkong.as6453.net (116.0.67.52)  103.504 ms if-ae-32-2.tcore2.svw-singapore.as6453.net (180.87.15.80)  306.423 ms if-ae-37-6.tcore2.hk2-hongkong.as6453.net (116.0.93.136)  294.489 ms
20  * * if-ae-2-2.tcore1.svw-singapore.as6453.net (180.87.12.1)  295.629 ms
21  if-ae-32-2.tcore2.svw-singapore.as6453.net (180.87.15.80)  297.415 ms * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * if-be-10-2.ecore2.svq-singapore.as6453.net (180.87.107.0)  291.017 ms  295.068 ms
25  * if-be-24-2.ecore1.svq-singapore.as6453.net (180.87.107.192)  285.090 ms *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Then tried `sudo service systemd-resolved status`  and got an error there saying

```
Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 ESCOC
```

Not sure if this is related to the problem am facing or not. But I am wondering if from terminal I can ping successfully, if am able to open from any other device, then why both of my browsers are unable to open this particular domain!!
BTW I already have tried removing caches, cookies from both browsers , restarted several times, tried to access by connecting to different router and different ISP , but everything is in vein . That domain is ending up with "connection timed out" message only ...

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly just after running `nslookup` I am able to access the domain from the browsers again. Though am not sure till now why the problem occured and how `nslookup` solved it!

But it's solved anyway...

EDIT

I faced the problem again after two days, which means above was not the solution. So after searching more about the issue , finally the solution proposed below worked for me ->

[can ping but not browse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273053/can-ping-but-not-browse)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).