# NetworkManager updates to a bad nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf on restart

Tags: network-manager, dns, resolv.conf

Whenever I restart my computer NetworkManager sets `/etc/resolv.conf` to this, my DNS stops working and I get this error in Chrome.

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search tampabay.rr.com
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Chrome error:

> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

I temporarily resolve the issue by setting `/etc/resolv.conf` to this.

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

I'm guessing NetworkManager expects a DNS server on my local machine at 127.0.0.53, and I don't have DNS running there. How can I permanetly set `8.8.8.8` as my nameserver? If it's really neccessary how do I setup DNS at `127.0.0.53`?

I read `man resolv.conf` but it didn't help me much.

I read this answer and created the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` with `nameserver 8.8.8.8` but it doesn't seem to have any effect: [DNS set to systemd's 127.0.0.53 - how to change permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012641/dns-set-to-systemds-127-0-0-53-how-to-change-permanently)

**Edit:**
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

The DNS cache program `unbound` was running on port :53 and preventing `dnsmasq` from starting. I uninstalled `unbound` and `dnsmasq` starts now. However it's saying it's only running on 0.0.0.0 for some reason. I figure it has to be running on 127.0.0.1:53. I reinstalled dnsmasq but it's acting the same. `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` is all commeted out.
On restart `/etc/resolv.conf` is now set to

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Not sure how to get `dnsmasq` running properly.

/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service

```
[Unit]
Description=dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
Requires=network.target
Wants=nss-lookup.target
Before=nss-lookup.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid

# Test the config file and refuse starting if it is not valid.
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --test

# We run dnsmasq via the /etc/init.d/dnsmasq script which acts as a
# wrapper picking up extra configuration files and then execs dnsmasq
# itself, when called with the "systemd-exec" function.
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-exec

# The systemd-*-resolvconf functions configure (and deconfigure)
# resolvconf to work with the dnsmasq DNS server. They're called like
# this to get correct error handling (ie don't start-resolvconf if the 
# dnsmasq daemon fails to start.
ExecStartPost=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-start-resolvconf
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-stop-resolvconf


ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

journalctl -e --unit dnsmasq.service

```
-- Reboot --
Jul 08 23:41:54 phil-desktopubuntu-18-04-1-lts systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Jul 08 23:41:54 phil-desktopubuntu-18-04-1-lts dnsmasq[7349]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Jul 08 23:41:54 phil-desktopubuntu-18-04-1-lts dnsmasq[7369]: started, version 2.80 cachesize 150
Jul 08 23:41:54 phil-desktopubuntu-18-04-1-lts dnsmasq[7369]: DNS service limited to local subnets
Jul 08 23:41:54 phil-desktopubuntu-18-04-1-lts dnsmasq[7369]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify dumpfile
Jul 08 23:41:54 phil-desktopubuntu-18-04-1-lts dnsmasq[7369]: read /etc/hosts - 7 addresses
Jul 08 23:41:54 phil-desktopubuntu-18-04-1-lts dnsmasq[7369]: no servers found in /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf, will retry
Jul 08 23:41:54 phil-desktopubuntu-18-04-1-lts systemd[1]: Started dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Also, the linked question has many approaches and none of that works for you?

Comment: It's expecting to see `dnsmasq` at `127.0.0.53`. `man dnsmasq;service dnsmasq status`

Comment: @waltinator I updated my question. Do you have any idea why dnsmasq is listening on 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Everything was commeted out in my `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`. I had to set the dns server.

/etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
server=8.8.8.8
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

These commands were helpful debugging

```
sudo systemctl status dnsmasq #dnsmasq should be running
sudo netstat -tulpn #dnsmasq should be listening on 0.0.0.0:53
nslookup debian.org localhost #should return IP address of debian.org
```

Comment: It **shouldn't** be necessary to set the DNS server explicitly, it should all be done by DHCP.  However I have been trying to get this to work as it should (i.e. automatically putting the upstream DNS server IP in /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf but I have yet to work out how to do it.