# resolv.conf mismatch netplan configuration

Tags: dns, netplan, resolv.conf

I'm setting up an Ubuntu Server 20.04 system as a gateway between my LAN and the WAN. I'm not able to configure the DNS properly.

I have 2 netplan config files for my 2 interfaces.

Internal eth interface (LAN)

```
root@gate:~# cat /etc/netplan/01-eth_int.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
        enp4s0:
            addresses: ['10.0.10.1/24']
            match:
                macaddress: 00:60:e0:76:9e:e7
            set-name: eth_int
  version: 2
```

External eth interface (WAN)

```
root@gate:~# cat /etc/netplan/02-eth_ext.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
        enp5s0:
            addresses: ['10.200.56.254/24']
            gateway4: 10.200.56.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [195.78.215.228, 195.78.223.228]
                addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
            match:
                macaddress: 00:60:e0:76:9e:e8
            set-name: eth_ext
  version: 2
```

On reboot the interfaces are configured according to netplan config files. But /etc/resolv.conf is misconfigured

```
root@gate:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

Test/check performed:

- /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink of ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
- systemd-resolve --status returns the correct DNS for eth_ext interface, but no global DNS (can be an issue?)

```
    root@gate:~# systemd-resolve --status
    Global
           LLMNR setting: no
    MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSOverTLS setting: no
          DNSSEC setting: no
        DNSSEC supported: no
              DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                          16.172.in-addr.arpa
                          168.192.in-addr.arpa
                          17.172.in-addr.arpa
                          18.172.in-addr.arpa
                          19.172.in-addr.arpa
                          20.172.in-addr.arpa
                          21.172.in-addr.arpa
                          22.172.in-addr.arpa
                          23.172.in-addr.arpa
                          24.172.in-addr.arpa
                          25.172.in-addr.arpa
                          26.172.in-addr.arpa
                          27.172.in-addr.arpa
                          28.172.in-addr.arpa
                          29.172.in-addr.arpa
                          30.172.in-addr.arpa
                          31.172.in-addr.arpa
                          corp
                          d.f.ip6.arpa
                          home
                          internal
                          intranet
                          lan
                          local
                          private
                          test

    Link 5 (eth_ext)
          Current Scopes: DNS
    DefaultRoute setting: yes
           LLMNR setting: yes
    MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSOverTLS setting: no
          DNSSEC setting: no
        DNSSEC supported: no
             DNS Servers: 195.78.215.228
                          195.78.223.228
                          8.8.8.8
                          8.8.4.4

    Link 4 (enp0s31f6)
          Current Scopes: none
    DefaultRoute setting: no
           LLMNR setting: yes
    MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSOverTLS setting: no
          DNSSEC setting: no
        DNSSEC supported: no

    Link 3 (eth_int)
          Current Scopes: none
    DefaultRoute setting: no
           LLMNR setting: yes
    MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSOverTLS setting: no
          DNSSEC setting: no
        DNSSEC supported: no

    Link 2 (enp3s0)
          Current Scopes: none
    DefaultRoute setting: no
           LLMNR setting: yes
    MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSOverTLS setting: no
          DNSSEC setting: no
        DNSSEC supported: no
```

- edited /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, setting and uncommenting DNS entry. A global DNS entry appears running systemd-resolve --status, but /etc/resolv.conf won't change

Obviously, this mismatch will prevent DNS to work properly

```
root@gate:~# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

root@gate:~#  nslookup heise.de 127.0.0.53
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The /etc/resolv.conf is correct.  What does `nslookup google.com 195.78.218.228` give you?

Comment: I suppose you meant 195.78.215.228 (the DNS I've set). In this case the nslookup works fine.

Comment: Why can you not reach the DNS server on 127.0.0.53, which is a local address?  systemd-resolved is running, as shown by systemd-resolve --status, so this looks like either a local firewall issue or a misconfiguration of resolved.

Comment: Well, could be a firewall issue. I didn't configure the firewall to route to local addresses. Have to check. ping 127.0.0.53 returns "Operation not permitted" But... what's this 127.0.0.53? A local address for a "virtual" DNS, that routes the DNS requests to the actual external DNS?

Answer (score 5):

You've mentioned, your `/etc/resolv.conf` is symlink of `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

To resolve this issue:

1. Unlink it: `$ sudo unlink /etc/resolv.conf`
2. `$ sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`
3. `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service`

The following information from `man systemd-resolved`:

```
/ETC/RESOLV.CONF
       Four modes of handling /etc/resolv.conf (see resolv.conf(5)) are supported:

       •   systemd-resolved maintains the /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf file for compatibility with
           traditional Linux programs. This file may be symlinked from /etc/resolv.conf. This file lists the
           127.0.0.53 DNS stub (see above) as the only DNS server. It also contains a list of search domains that are
           in use by systemd-resolved. The list of search domains is always kept up-to-date. Note that
           /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf should not be used directly by applications, but only through a
           symlink from /etc/resolv.conf. This file may be symlinked from /etc/resolv.conf in order to connect all
           local clients that bypass local DNS APIs to systemd-resolved with correct search domains settings. This
           mode of operation is recommended.

       •   A static file /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf is provided that lists the 127.0.0.53 DNS stub (see above) as
           only DNS server. This file may be symlinked from /etc/resolv.conf in order to connect all local clients
           that bypass local DNS APIs to systemd-resolved. This file does not contain any search domains.

       •   systemd-resolved maintains the /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf file for compatibility with traditional
           Linux programs. This file may be symlinked from /etc/resolv.conf and is always kept up-to-date, containing
           information about all known DNS servers. Note the file format's limitations: it does not know a concept of
           per-interface DNS servers and hence only contains system-wide DNS server definitions. Note that
           /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf should not be used directly by applications, but only through a symlink
           from /etc/resolv.conf. If this mode of operation is used local clients that bypass any local DNS API will
           also bypass systemd-resolved and will talk directly to the known DNS servers.

       •   Alternatively, /etc/resolv.conf may be managed by other packages, in which case systemd-resolved will read
           it for DNS configuration data. In this mode of operation systemd-resolved is consumer rather than provider
           of this configuration file.

       Note that the selected mode of operation for this file is detected fully automatically, depending on whether
       /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf or lists 127.0.0.53 as DNS server.
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver!

Comment: saved my life too!

Answer (score -1):

I notice you didn't specify dhcp4: false on your lan and didn't assign a nameserver - that may be your problem?

I just recently setup my ubuntu machine as a router and after a lot of struggle I gave up on naming the interfaces and let them as eno1 / enp1s0 in the yaml file (BTW I combined their description in a single file that I named `01-router-all.yaml` so that I only have one file to edit when making changes). I think that I faced a race condition with the dhcp server service starting before the network service had named the interfaces as per my .yaml.

Here is my working `/etc/netplan/01-router-all.yaml` if it helps (I am somewhat cheating and assigning public DNS, as I still need to setup a DNS server on my machine):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd

  ethernets:
    # eno1 = wan1
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.8/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [9.9.9.9, 1.1.1.1]
        search: []

    # enp1s0 = lan
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.9.1/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [9.9.9.9, 1.1.1.1]
        search: []
```

Comment: I skipped declaring DNS for internal ETH because the DNS will "travel" through the external one. Anyway, I copied the configuration on the internal eth. systemd-resolve --status lists the DNS addresses on this interface, too. /etc/resolv.conf still displays 127.0.0.53 after reboot (so, still no ping to names)

Comment: dhcp4: false also changed nothing

Comment: DHCP defaults to false.

Comment: I supposed it was redundant to set it since I set a static IP, that's why I skied it from the configuration

Comment: @il_mix, I suspect that this page can help: [DNS set to systemd's 127.0.0.53 - how to change permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012641/dns-set-to-systemds-127-0-0-53-how-to-change-permanently)

I wonder if it's normal that Current scopes for eth_int is set to none:
`Link 3 (eth_int) /    Current Scopes: none`

Comment: I've read several answers/solution of that post. My current solution was to disable systemd-resolved, set resolv-conf "manually" (actually via webmin) and use bind9 to link external requests to the DNS. The gateway works and it's already instlalled; will be a problem for my colleagues if I stast testing alternatives. Will do when I have the chance, though