# Cannot connect via WiFi / DHCP after using ProtonVPN

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet, vpn

In my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, after using ProtonVPN, and rebooting while connected, WiFi messed up.

If I try via WiFi:

```
$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not connect to ar.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (200.236.31.4). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to ar.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2801:82:80ff:8000::5). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
...
```

and I cannot surf the web via Firefox, e.g.
If I connect via LAN, both things work.
I don't think the router is blocking my WiFi.

With the help of:

1. https://forum.zorin.com/t/unable-to-access-internet-after-using-protonvpn/2142
2. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=350047
3. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/network-connected-but-no-internet-4175687745/page2.html

I found "spurious" connection `ipv6leakintrf0`, which I removed with `nmcli connection delete <name>`, followed by `rm -rf ~/.cache/protonvpn` and reboot.

As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357086/why-do-two-ubuntu-systems-in-the-same-network-behave-differently-in-dns-resoluti/1357165?noredirect=1#comment2324000_1357165), I can connect if using a fixed IP.

**How can I fix this, without manually setting a fixed IP for the WiFi connection (i.e., using DHCP)?**

Comment: How exactly are you connecting to proton VPN?

Comment: @muru - I followed [instructions at the official site](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-tool/#cli). But I am not sure about the direct relevance of this here. As said, I am almost sure the problem started with the events described. But now the problem is present without being connected to Proton VPN.

Answer (score 2):

Update -- Logout of Proton VPN and then log back in when presented with the above symptoms. This will workaround the problem. The overall issue, I believe is with the app itself on Debian based OSes, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to confirm. This is not a resolution, but will allow you to keep on keeping on.

Post 1: I disconnected from ProtonVPN and confirmed I was unable to connect still. Reading an article from the Proton site they mentioned something about an account timeout. I logged out of ProtonVPN (not just disconnect, but logged out with my account from the app) and my internet functionality returned to normal.

Rebooted and confirmed the same. I'll continue to monitor, but hard to imagine just logging out of the App resolved the issue. Also weird as I was able to connect to ProtonVPN prior to logging out.

Just wanted to share.