# I have to set nameserver and restart networking on every login

Tags: networking, 17.10, dns

At the moment, each time I restart my computer and login, I need to run

```
sudo su
echo -e "nameserver 8.8.8.8\nnameserver 8.8.4.4" > /etc/resolv.conf
service networking restart
```

To make a long story short, yesterday my internet connection worked perfectly fine. This morning  I wasn't able to load or download anything. I found the above solution, but I don't want to use those commands whenever I enter my Ubuntu account.

How can I solve this problem?

**P.S.** I have a workstation with no wifi network card. Just a standard network card with wire.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. On the top right of my screen (Ubuntu 17.10) I have the network icon which I use to access NetworkManager.  Right clicking it I get Wired Connection which allows me to edit.  Under Network and Wired I click the gear icon to edit, then click IPv4 (because my that's what my network uses) and could change the Automatic.DHCP to manual & enter the google DNS addresses you used in your given quick.fix. Then click Apply (to save it)

Comment: @guiverc Could you make a full answer.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409625/struggling-with-always-restart-the-networking

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know it was prohibited.

Comment: @muru That one's been deleted, so this one can stay open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to change the DNS IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip)

Answer (score 2):

On the top right of my screen (Ubuntu 17.10) I have the network icon which I use to access NetworkManager.

Right clicking it I get Wired Connection which allows me to edit (Wired Connection, Wired Settings)

A Settings Window will open at the Network page, where you click the gear logo in the Wired section of the screen.

For my network (IPv4 is used on my network) I'd then click IPv4 and go to the DNS setting, where you can enter the provided quick.fix DNS address in the box (seperated by commas as it'll say on screen)

When done click Apply (top right) to save the change.