# resolv.conf take a localhost as DNS

Tags: dns

When read   `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```bsh
me@alpha:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf | tail -3                                                                                
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

I got the idea of DNS from [The Internet: IP Addresses & DNS - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5o8CwafCxnU) and aware that DNS is [Google Public DNS - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS)

How could the default namesever is a localhost address? I guess it impossible accessing  to external services.

Comment: Name resolution is not based on `/etc/resolv.conf` only.  That file is part of a dynamic system, the details of which depend on the exact version of Ubuntu that you use.  See for example [What is the proper way to change the DNS IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip).  Other questions on AU also refer to the same theme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In recent Ubuntu releases, domain name resolution is handled by **systemd-resolved**, and 127.0.0.53 is only a stub listener created by **systemd-resolved**. You can find out the actual DNS server that handles DNS queries by using the command

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
```

Look for the line that starts with `DNS Servers`.

You can learn more about **systemd-resolved** from its [manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html).

Comment: Alternatively you can check the service logs with: `systemctl status systemd-resolved`