# Some Internet addresses are blocked or unavailable

Tags: networking, 20.04

On my Ubuntu 20.04 machine it seems that some internet addresses are blocked or unavailable. I cannot not reach github.com and askubuntu.com from the browser. Also cloning from github via the terminal is not possible. Other websites work like google.com.

Even `sudo apt update` seems to have connection problems.
[image: terminal warning]
[image: firefox connection fails]

**Update:**
I have run `systemd-resolve --status` for DNS info and here is the output:
[image]

Comment: are you behind some company firewall or so ? What is your DNS server?

Comment: I am at my home network, how can i check the dns server?

Comment: @pLumo i have updated my question with the output of systemd-resolve --status

Comment: This is your providers DNS server, change it to something else. It seems to have problems. Use 1.0.0.1 or 8.8.8.8 (Google) --> https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip

Comment: But when I visit the website from my phone in the same network I don't have any problems

Comment: Your phone might use a different DNS. If you [google the IP](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=2a02%3A908%3A2%3Ab%3A%3A1), you will find a lot of sites with people complainging :-D

Comment: @pLumo yes thanks! Shall i delete my question?

Comment: No, it is marked as duplicate now and linked to the other Question. It may still be useful for others.