# DNS won't change problem

Tags: 20.04, dns

I've been trying to change my DNS in my ubuntu 20.04 via the wifi settings. I select my internet network and go to it's settings. In the ipv4 tab I change the DNS but when I click the apply button the settings window closes completely and when I go back the settings have returned back to normal. Any fixes? Maybe a way I can change my DNS using other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the default network settings GUI crash on me before when trying to do certain things. I worked around it by running `nm-connection-editor` from terminal. It's an alternative network settings GUI that has more options than the default and always works for me.

When changing certain network options I have found I have to enable/disable the network connection afterwards to get the new settings to take.

Comment: This actually worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is using the NetworkManager service to handle the network configuration. There is 2 different levels of modification, specific for a network or system wide.

#### Specific Network

- Modify the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MY_NETWORK.nmconnection` file (**requires root)**, modify the following section:

```
[ipv4]
dns-search=1.1.1.1;
```

- Use the `nmtui` command  (**without root**) that gives you a configuration wizzard.

#### System wide

1. Update `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

```
[Resolve]
DNS=1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
FallbackDNS=8.8.4.4
```

2. Restart system resolved: `service systemd-resolved restart`
3. Run `systemd-resolve --status`

the output should look like this:

```
Global
         DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
                      8.8.8.8
...
```

References:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588658/override-ubuntu-20-04-dns-using-systemd-resolved
- [What is the proper way to change the DNS IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip)